# Proper Autoprefix Plugin for my less middleware for node expressjs

Tags: css, node.js, express, less

Currently I use less-middleware (https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-middleware). I am not satisfied with this solution, because less-middlware create a compiled css file. I want a memorized solution I can route via expressjs.

Besides, I want to work with a proper autoprefix solution, because there are many nice css technologies I cant use because I would need to much time to add the vendor prefixes.

1. Do anybody know a better solution for instant less compilation without outputing a separate css file.
2. Can this solution offer some kind of autoprefixing functionality?
3. Does offer less-middleware offer an autoprefixing functionality. I have not found something in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to reformat your question, because of:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

I found https://github.com/toogle/express-less/blob/master/lib/express-less.js according their package.json file, Express LESS middleware uses the latest version of Node Less.

In their code the call `less.render()` here: https://github.com/toogle/express-less/blob/master/lib/express-less.js#L68 and more information  can be found here: http://lesscss.org/usage/#programmatic-usage

Since version 2 of Less you can use plugins. An autoprefix plugin is available at: https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix

So you should be able to use the follow code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    expressLess = require('express-less'),
    autoprefixer = require('less-plugin-autoprefix');

var app = express();
app.use('/less-css', expressLess(__dirname + '/less',  { plugins: [autoprefixer] }));
```

Also see: http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-using-a-plugin-in-code

Notice i did not test the above code. I wondered how to set the autoprefixer option. According to https://github.com/plus3network/gulp-less#using-plugins you should use:

```
var autoprefixerPlugin = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
autoprefixer = new autoprefixerPlugin({options});
var app = express();
    app.use('/less-css', expressLess(__dirname + '/less',  { plugins: [autoprefixer] }));
```

Comment: This code not work. I just test it. According to https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-middleware#options, `plugins` is not an options. I try another way currently

Comment: I find the working way explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43423782/2412797

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation of Less Engine](http://lesscss.org/), the way to use a plugin is the following:

> `less.render(myCSS, { plugins: [myPlugin] })`
>
> *Source: [http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-using-a-plugin-in-code](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-using-a-plugin-in-code_)*

Then according to [the documentation of Less Middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/less-middleware), the way to add options into second parameter of `render()` function is the following:

> The `options.render` is passed directly into the `less.render` with minimal defaults or changes by the middleware.
>
> *Source: [https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware#render-options](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware#render-options_)*

So according to [the documentation of Less Autoprefixer](https://github.com/less/less-plugin-autoprefix) ande the documentation of [Express Engine](http://expressjs.com/), the definitive and true way to use it is using this code:

```
var express = require('express'),
    lessMiddleware = require('less-middleware'),
    lessPluginAutoprefix = require('less-plugin-autoprefix'),
    app = express(),
    autoprefixPlugin = new lessPluginAutoprefix({ 
        browsers: ["last 2 versions"] 
    });

app.use(lessMiddleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public'), {
    render: {
        plugins: [
            autoprefixPlugin
        ]
    }
}));
```

[This was implemented and tested in the NodeAtlas NPM module](https://github.com/NodeAtlas/node-atlas/blob/master/lib/server.js#L434).